# Android Studio - project explorer not in correct shape

Tags: android, android-studio

I don't know if it is the place to ask this question, but i thinks it's more relevant to ask it here than in http://android.stackexchange.com.

The android studio project explorer always is like image below:
[image]

But in one of my new projects it became like below:
[image]

It's a bit confusing i could not find manifest and other xmls easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are switching between [Android project view and Project files view](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/index.html#ProjectFiles).

There is a menu on top of the tree view to change it.

Example screenshots:

- Package view:

[image]

- Android project view:

[image]

- Project files view:

[image]

Comment: Wow i've never touched that. it was automatically changed i believe.

Comment: It has happened to us all :)

Answer (score 1):

> Android Studio creates the default structure for your project and
>   opens the development environment. If your app supports more than one
>   form factor, Android Studio creates a module folder with complete
>   source files for each of them .

[image]

You should check **[Projects Overview](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/index.html)** .You can change its structure by selecting above picture .